# Is the kernel mapping compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $k \in \mathcal{C}([0, 1]\times [0,1])$ a continuous function. I need to prove that the following  mapping is compact, $T: \mathcal{C}([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}([0,1]): $
$$ (Tu)(t) = \int_0^1 k(t,s) u(s) ds, \,\,\, u \in \mathcal{C}([0,1]).$$

What I am confused with is if by compact mapping one means compact operator. Are these equivalent notions ? Do you have any suggestion how to approach the problem ?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing. I think using the definition for any bounded sequence $x_n$ in $X$, $Tx_n$ contains a converging subsequence is the easiest way to attack.

Comment: Thanks. No norms are provided. Which one should one take ? The sup norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to the comments: yes, it is most likely that $C(X)$ is meant with the supremum norm.

Let $(u_n)\subset C[0,1]$ be a bounded seqeunce, say there exists $M>0$ s.t. $\|u_n\|_\infty\le M$ for all $n$. We shall show that $Tu_n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Well, what can we use to do that, if not the infamous [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem)?

Note first that, if $x\in [0,1]$, then $|Tu_n(x)|\le\int_0^1 |k(x,s)u_n(s)|ds\le\sup_{r,s\in X}|k(r,s)|\cdot\sup_{s\in X}|u_n(s)|=\|k\|_{C([0,1]^2)}\cdot\|u_n\|\le\|k\|\cdot M$. This shows that $\|Tu_n\|\le\|k\|\cdot M$ and this is true for all $n$, so the family $\{Tu_n\}$ is uniformly bounded.

Now given $r,s\in [0,1]$ we have
$$|Tu_n(r)-Tu_n(s)|\le\int_0^1|k(r,t)-k(s,t)|\cdot|u_n(t)|dt\le M\int_0^1|k(r,t)-k(s,t)|dt$$
Since $k$ is continuous on a compact set, it is uniformly continuous; therefore, given $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $\delta:=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ (depending only on $\varepsilon$ and $k$!) such that $$\|(a,b)-(a',b')\|_{[0,1]^2}<\delta\implies|k(a,b)-k(a',b')|<\varepsilon$$

So assume that $\varepsilon>0$ is given. For the quantity $\varepsilon/M>0$ take the corresponding $\delta$, i.e. take $\delta=\delta(\frac{\varepsilon}{M})$. Now if $|r-s|<\delta$ we have that
$$\|(r,t)-(s,t)\|_{[0,1]^2}=\sqrt{|r-s|^2+|t-t|^2}=|r-s|<\delta$$
for any $t\in[0,1]$, so $|k(r,t)-k(s,t)|<\varepsilon/M$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. But our earlier computation shows that $|Tu_n(r)-Tu_n(s)|<\varepsilon$. We have just shown that $\{Tu_n\}$ is *equicontinuous*.

Well, now that it's applicable, apply Arzela-Ascoli. Wait! Didn't we just verify the definition of a compact operator?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, since the Arzela-Ascoli theorem assures that $Tu_n$ has a (uniformly) convergent subsequence, which is required for compactness. I have an additional question: Why the definition of compact operators includes the kernel $k(t,s)$ ? Why is this important?

Comment: @user996159 The definition of a compact operator is abstract, it is the following: an operator $T:X\to Y$ is compact iff for any bounded sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ the sequence $(Tx_n)$ in $Y$ has a convergent subsequence. I dont understand what do you mean?

Comment: The integral includes not only the argument of $T$, i.e. $u$ but also the function $k(s,t).$ Why is the inclusion of $k$ essential in providing a reasonable definition of a compact operator ?

Comment: @user996159 Because you are integrating with respect to one variable but you want the result to be a function in some variable, that's why you put a 2-variable thing in the integral. You need continuity of $k$ for the answer to work. Now what do you mean essential? these are compact operators indeed as we just proved but they are only some examples of compact operators, there are other examples out there as well

Comment: Thanks. It is clear now.

Comment: I got an additional question. By equicontinuous do you mean uniformly equicontinuous ?

Comment: @user996159 yes

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have a last question. The Arzela-Ascoli theorem proves that every sequence $(Tu_n)$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence. It doesn't say if the limit of the subsequence belongs to the space one considers. In other words, in a general situation, does the Arzela-Ascoli theorem proves a sequence of functions is compact or rather relative compact in respect to some bigger space?

Comment: @user996159 Uniform limits of sequences of continuous functions are again continuous functions. I'm sorry but these are things you should be answering yourself at this point